# Installing JavaFX plugin into Ecipse Kepler and getting errors

Tags: eclipse, javafx, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install the following JavaFX plugin

http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/1.2.0/site/

I am following directions from this site:

http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html
I the xtext software that the site recommended but I am getting the following error:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: e(fx)clipse - IDE - PDE 1.2.0.201501301049 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.pde.feature.feature.group 1.2.0.201501301049)
  Missing requirement: Core 1.2.0.201501301049 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.pde.core 1.2.0.201501301049) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.resources 3.9.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: e(fx)clipse - IDE - PDE 1.2.0.201501301049 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.pde.feature.feature.group 1.2.0.201501301049)
    To: org.eclipse.fx.ide.pde.core [1.2.0.201501301049]

How do I install the proper software to fix this issue?
What download web address has this specific download that I can point to using the Install New Software feature of Eclipse

Thank you sooo much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that release 3.9.0 (or later) of the `org.eclipse.core.resources` plugin is required. This is part of the Eclipse Luna (4.4) release, so you can't use this code with Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: Should i just switch to using Eclipse Luna  then? I would hate having to reload all of my plugins. Which eclipse is better? Why is it not supported with my version

Comment: You can import plugins from another Eclipse installation via File > Import > Install > From Existing Installation. Just be careful and only import what you really need, to reduce the chances of problems. But this is still sometimes error-prone because the plugins you have in your Kepler installation might not be compatible with Luna.

Comment: The current e(fx)clipse release relies on code which is new in Eclipse Luna so it won't run on earlier releases.